# How to track who published a message in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, audit-logging

Wondering if there is a way to force a broker to include information (perhaps in a header) about the publisher that pushed a Record.

The publisher can do this, but it can easily avoid it too.

Answer (score 0):

"Force" a broker? No, brokers only receive bytes of a record. That information would generally be done at the producer, but even then you cannot force usage of a certain serializer or message format (for the later, Confluent Server offers broker-side schema validation, but then you'd run into the issue that clients can provide fake information).
With that note, CloudEvents defines a "spec" for metadata that is recommended for each message in event driven systems.

In my opinion, best you can do is force authorization + authentication policies to track client/credentials used to access a set of topics.

OpenPolicyAgent or Apache Ranger have Kafka plugins that can assist with this